# How to add multiple Jars to be excluded from Gradle Build

Tags: android, build, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am using the following segment in build.gradle to exclude a jar from my build process:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', exclude: 'androidannotations-api-2.7.1.jar' , include: '*.jar')
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I exclude 1 more jar using this command ? i.e I have to exclude multiple jars from the build process.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This syntax should work:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', excludes: ['androidannotations-api-2.7.1.jar', 'foo.jar', 'bar.jar'], include: '*.jar')
```

You can see an example of it in the Gradle docs at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html where they show the difference between `include:` and `includes:` and also show some path globbing. Those docs don't explicitly state that `excludes:` is supported, but if you dig into the DSL references at  http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/ConfigurableFileTree.html you can see a `setExcludes` method.